# Use Google Maps API to display an image/camera feed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use GMaps API to display a camera feed or an image.
As you can find in Google's "developper's guide", the code to display GMAP with a moon picture replacing the map is here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image?hl=fr .

I think the interesting part, for me, is

```
return '//mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw' +
              '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
              (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.jpg';
```

How can I change this line to get my image (or camera feed) displayed ?
Is it only possible to use a camera feed and not a simple image ?

If you are able to find a documentation that I haven't already found and that explains what is returned and why, it would be appreciated :)

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT :** 
I tried to replace the returned string to put my own camera feed. 
I also tried to use my own image, replacing '//mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw'.
I also did a few changes on the string to see how it reacts.
The result was the same for every case : complete failure.

Comment: Please reference what you have tried already in your post.

Comment: I edited my post to add what I tried.

Comment: what image do you want it to have and what type is the image you want it to replace with?

Comment: I want to replace the moon image by another image (no matter if jpg, png, ...) or by a camera feed accessible by a specific URL